# Office 365 workflow options

Tags: workflow, office-365

I have to create some custom workflows on an office 365 SharePoint environment.  What are the options I have apart from SharePoint Designer.  I used to do this using visual studio some time ago but I dont think it is supported anymore.  Plus if I am using SharePoint Designer do I have to create it on the production environment (office 365 environment) at once or can I first do it in a staging environment and then publish it to office 365 later on?

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 has got no testing environment, you can only create a separate site collection and every workflow you test there will not affect any other site collection.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Visual Studio. But you can create and test your workflows with SharePoint Designer in a development environment (even an on-prem), export the workflow from SharePoint designer and then use PowerShell to deploy the workflow to staging and production.

This requires a little bit of work:

1. To extract the workflow from development export it to a WSP, rename it to *.cab and grab the *.xaml files, which are the workflow definitions
2. Deploy the workflow definition and subscription using PowerShell (I have created a PowerShell commandlet for both steps - see [here](http://www.rickenberg.net/Blog/Post/4/Flexible-SharePoint-Deployment))